# More pre-trained embeddings for PyTorch Big Graph

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, graphs

Apart from the entire [wikidata](https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/torchbiggraph/wikidata_translation_v1.tsv.gz), are there any other [PyTorch Big Graph](https://github.com/facebookresearch/PyTorch-BigGraph) pre-trained graph embeddings on smaller sized knowledge graph, like freebase-15k? I do not have the resources to build it from scratch.